# Why is my subclass object always empty even though I have a proper constructor in Java?

Tags: java, subclass, superclass

I have this subclass that inherits from a superclass and I've noticed that the objects of that subclass seem to be empty if I try to print it out.
I've never come across an issue like this before and would really appreciate your help.

I have this subclass:

```
public class OnetimeAppointment extends Appointment {
    int year, month, day;
    private String description;



    public OnetimeAppointment(int year, int month, int day, String description)
    {
        super();
        System.out.println(this.year);
        System.out.println(year);
        this.year = year;
        this.month = month; 
        this.day = day;
        this.description = description;
        System.out.println(this.year);
    
        }

    public int getYear() 
    {
        return year;
    }
    public int getMonth() 
    {
        return month;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean occursOn(int year, int month, int day) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object otherObject)
    {
        return false;
    }

}
}
```

Here is the superclass:

```
public abstract class Appointment {
    private String description;

    
    public Appointment() {
        description = "";
    }
    
    public abstract boolean equals(Object otherObject);
    
    
    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }
    
    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    
    public abstract boolean occursOn(int year, int month, int day);

    
    public String toString() {
        return description;
    }
    
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Appointment app = new OnetimeAppointment(2020, 11, 1, "Dentist");
        System.out.println(app);

}
```

Comment: I would recommend to debug it in the IDE. You can check state of each field after each step. This is very helpful for understanding.

Comment: Field `description` in `OnetimeAppointment` is **hiding** field `description` in `Appointment`, so the `toString()` of `Appointment` returns an empty string, and hence `println(app)` prints an empty string.

Comment: @andreas I never noticed that! how do I fix it though?

Comment: Give `Appointment` a `description` constructor parameter and pass description in the `super()` call of the subclass constructor.

Comment: Depends upon what you want. Do you really need description field in child class, if it is already available in parent?

Comment: in you subclass **OnetimeAppointment** you create new field **description** the same name with the super class field and that field you use it in toString() methode  and its steal empty because you initialize the subclass field, so all you need to do is to delete the  **description** field from your subclass